# How to get inner div without id with jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I want to pick inner `div` without `id` or `class`

```
<div id="gjs">
   <div>
     pick inner div without id or class
   </div>
</div>
```

In jQuery:

```
$("Selector=?").html();
```

Comment: <div><div>abc</div></div>

Comment: `$('div > div')` ?

Comment: i tried this but can't

Comment: <div id="gjs">
<div>abc</div>
</div>

gjs is editor id but i have to get inner div html

Comment: i want this result

<div>abc</div>

Comment: @Alive i want full div of abc like this
<div>abc</div>

Comment: @SohailAsghar  did you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/eho6ouye/1/

```js
console.log($('#gjs').find('div').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gjs"> <div>abc</div> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.gjs').find('div');
```

Read this doc:
[jQuery Find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: That returns a jQuery object. not what OP expects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the element itself `<div>abc</div>`, then just do this: `$('#gjs > div')[0]`

That applies for any jQuery object. `$('.someSelector')[0]` will give you the element of the object, same as `document.getElementById('id')`
Where as `$('.someSelector')` will give you a jQuery object for said selector